# De Morgan to avoid ORs in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, demorgans-law

So from what I know `OR`'s in a query can make it difficult to create a performant query plan using indices. Is it at all useful to use De Morgan's laws to turn `WHERE (X OR Y)` into `WHERE NOT (NOT X AND NOT Y)`?

If using De Morgan's laws is useful in this case, is it still useful if the actual WHERE clause I'm interested in is

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE [...other conditions...]
AND NOT (X NOT IN (v1,v2,v3,...) AND Y NOT IN (u1,u2,u3,...)
[...other conditions...]
```

Where the values in the `NOT IN` clauses change according to the query parameters (the query is generated dynamically).

I have an index: `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_X_Y ON Table1 (X,Y)`

Comment: Try it and see, inspect the execution plans for each and compare them.

Comment: Actually `WHERE (X OR Y)` is probably not sargable to begin with, so I doubt that rewriting as you have done would get around the problem and become sargable.

Comment: Sometime simplicity and maintainability should be given preference as well. `A OR B` is mush easier to read and understand than above solution. Modern DBMS would be capable to run an OR and i think it will behave same way as your query. IN() always translated to multiple = so eventually your above SQL will be translated to multiple ORs. You can put the `v1,v2,v3,...` in a table and join them to get better performance

Comment: Using de Morgan can help sometimes. I remember an Itzik Ben Gan example of this - but   here the transformation is no more sargable than the original

Comment: @MartinSmith AFAIR de Morgan's only helps if for whatever reason the compiler did not notice the possible transformation. But it usually does.

Comment: "Where the values in the NOT IN clauses change according to the query parameters (the query is generated dynamically)." sounds like you should be using some kind of Table Valued Parameter.

Comment: @Charlieface I am, this is simplified to make the question to the point

Comment: `IN` with scalar values is optimized very differently from `IN` subqueries, so it really depends what you are actually doing.

Comment: That's fair, I thought `X NOT IN (v1,v2,v3,...)` makes it clear that the values are scalar but I see how it can be misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if "avoiding" ORs by using De Morgan will help. In the past I have tried to do so as well, but if I remember correctly, I have not noticed any performance improvements.

However, if performance is a serious bottleneck here, you could consider using `UNION` or `UNION ALL`. Not the nicest solution, but it might be effective.

The query

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE (ConditionX) OR (ConditionY)
```

would become something like

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE (ConditionX)
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE (ConditionY)
```

However, **beware that such a solution using `UNION` or `UNION ALL` might behave differently if your original query would return duplicate rows**. (But I assume that you also try to avoid duplicate rows in the result set.)

Also note that `X IN (A, B, C)` might be interpreted internally as an OR as well: `(X = A OR X = B OR X = C)`. I am not sure if this will have any effects on performance as well. (I simply assume it does, but I am not sure.)

You could also consider using separate indexes for X and Y.

Regarding all these suggestions, I would strongly consider Dale K's and Tim Biegeleisen's advice to investigate query performance by looking at query execution plans to see if indexes will be used or not and what their effects will be.

Tip: If you perform query optimizations by completely changing a query's structure, don't forget to include some comments to explain to colleagues and your future self why you chose to do so. For documentation purposes, you might also want keep your original query in comments as well. ;)

Comment: "X IN (A, B, C) might be interpreted internally as an OR as well" there is no *might* that's exactly what it does.

Comment: IN is listed as a sargable operator which is what I was really interested in. Problem is, while NOT IN is sargable it usually doesn't improve performance.

Comment: Either way, we did go for UNION ALL in the end (there is a dedup step anyway later in the query), so accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Example
With Test table

```
create table test (id int, A int,B int,ValueName char(200));
create index ix_test_a_b on test (A,B) include(Id) ;
```

table size about  1400 rows

```
select id,A,B from test
where  (A=12 or a=14);
```

Main operation   -  `Index Seek`
Plan

[image]

Query

```
select id,A,B from test
where not  (not A=12 and not a=14);
```

Main operation   -  `Nested Loops`

Plan
[image]

For query

```
select id,A,B from test
where (A) in (12,14) and (B) in (24,25);
```

Main operation Index Seek
Plan
[image]

For query

```
select id,A,B from test
where not ( (A) not in (12,14) and (B) not in (24,25));
```

Main operation Index Scan
Plan
[image]

Comment: Your example is not representative for OP's use case, which concerns filters on two different columns OR'ed together.

Comment: I'll add example for different columns.